# IIS website - can ping server IP but cant reach it by domain name

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, domain, a-record

I have an A record pointing to my server via its' public IP.
It is set with the following host/value pair: `@,   47.91.42.224`
I can reach my server with this IP as it's the primary way I connect to it.
In my IIS site I have 2 bindings

- `mysomedomainname.com` (not an actual name)
- `www.mysomedomainname.com` (not an actual name)

both having IP address set to servers' private address. There are a total of 3 options for the IP dropdown

- `All unassigned`
- `internal server address`
- `some IPv6 address`

I've tried using unassigned instead as well, but no luck. While I can ping the server, I can't reach my site via domain as it gives me a timeout. It's definitely not a content issue as there is a plain HTML document with 1 line of text.

```
NSLOOKUP mysomedomainname.com
```

Executed from the server machinbe gives the following result:

```
NSLOOKUP : Non-authoritative answer:
At line:1 char:1
+ NSLOOKUP mysomedomainname.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Non-authoritative answer::String) [], R 
   emoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Server:  UnKnown
Address:  100.100.2.138

Name:    mysomedomainname.com
Address:  47.91.42.224
```

Comment: And what does `nslookup` say?

Comment: `NSLOOKUP http://mysomedomainname.com/` ->
`NSLOOKUP : *** UnKnown can't find http://mysomedomainname.com/
: Non-existent domain`

Comment: `nslookup mysomedomainname.com`

Like that. Post the output in your original question. You'll probably get some answers then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Was an actual issue with port 80 as cloud provider had custom security groups configuration.